# Swift Conventions - Alert or Push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I am looking for a solution to providing the user with some information that they may not need to act upon, but is generally useful to know.

I have some JSON / DB operations that perform on a separate thread, when the opertion is finished I think it would be beneficial for the user to see a message that tells them something has changed e.g "12 New Items Added" or something to that effect.

The solutions I have found thus far are either using an alert to show this information or perhaps push notification?

I have added the question mark there as I am fairly sure that isn't the correct approach in this situation.

If anyone has used the toastr popups library before that is something very close to what I am after, but for Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest using an alert, according to Apple's guidelines alerts should only be used if it is something that a user must act upon or something that they must know.

I would suggest that you use a toast or something to that effect to make the user aware of what has been done as it's much less intrusive.

Here is a tutorial that I have found on how to implement it:

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/implement-toast-message-ios-using-swift